# Center title in latex-rendered text for matplotlib figure

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, latex, data-visualization

I would like to center a title for a Matplotlib figure which includes a newline return (\) when rendering it LaTeX style

inserting a simple return code for latex \\ in the middle of the title will work, but will not have it centered so that the newline is awkwardly shifted from the first line.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
plt.title(r"\center{\textbf{Some title \\ with with a newline}}")
```

or

```py
plt.title(r"\begin{centering}{\textbf{Some title \\ with a newline}\end{centering}")
```

won't work

When I input the previously cited lines, I get no title output at all on the figure. I do not have a LaTeX error on the python command interpreter though.

Comment: What about: `plt.title(r"$\textbf{Some title}\\ \textbf{with a newline}$")`?

Comment: This seems to work for such a short title.
My true title however contains a mathmode symbol and is longer.
Even if I take the mathmode symbol away so as not to break down the math line, the longer title doesn't seem to be centered...

`plt.title(r"$\textbf{Augmentation factor (A) for intracavity intensity} \\ \textbf{with different deposition metals}$")`
And i would like the A factor to be `\mathcal{A}`

Comment: Is `plt.title(r"$\textbf{Augmentation factor (A) for intracavity intensity}$"
          "\n"
          r"$\textbf{with different deposition metals}$")` useful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily use `\n` to get newline within `plt.title()`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rc('text', usetex=True)

t = np.arange(0., 5., 0.2)

plt.plot(t, t/5000,)
plt.title(r"$\textbf{Some title}$"
          "\n"
          r"$\textbf{with a formula}:$"
          "\n"
          r"$y=t/5000$")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: That works, great way to make your way around my problem! thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a proper LaTex installed on your system, and all set up to use LaTex from within matplotlib, you have to set a specific LaTex preamble in which `/begin{center} ... /end{center}` is available.

Here is a working example.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

custom_preamble = {                                                                          
    "text.latex.preamble":                                                                   
        r"\usepackage{amsmath}" # for the align, center,... environment
        ,
    }   
plt.rcParams.update(custom_preamble)                                                         
plt.figure(figsize= (6,4),tight_layout = True)                                               

t = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0, 100)
s = np.cos(4 * np.pi * t) + 2
plt.plot(t, s,label='your legend')

plt.xlabel(r'\textbf{bold (s)}')                                                        
plt.ylabel('\\textit{italic (\N{DEGREE SIGN}/sec)}', fontsize=16)                   
plt.title(r'\begin{center}Your title\\ new line, centered: ($-e^{i\pi}$, centered\end{center}')                  
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

This gives:

[image]