# matplotlib text alignment when using latex

Tags: matplotlib, text, latex

Before, this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams.update({
    "text.usetex": True})

plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1])
plt.xlabel('hello\nnew world')
```

generated a plot with centered alignment in the x label, something like here:
[image]

But now I get this left aligned text:

[image]

I am not sure if matplotlib or latex version changed, but wondering how should I adapt my code to get back to the usual center alignment.

Thank you!

Related question:
[Center title in latex-rendered text for matplotlib figure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56359809/center-title-in-latex-rendered-text-for-matplotlib-figure)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `plt.rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = r'\centering'` solved the problem. Here is the full code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams.update({
    "text.usetex": True})

plt.rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = r'\centering'

plt.figure(figsize=(2,2))
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1])
plt.xlabel('hello \n new world')
```

[image]

`\n` can be replaced by `\\\` or `\\newline` (as an additional `\` is needed as escape character) or `\linebreak` (so that it doesn't start a new paragraph).

Another option is to put the centering locally:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams.update({
    "text.usetex": True})

plt.figure(figsize=(2,2))
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1])
plt.xlabel('\\begin{center} hello \linebreak new world \end{center}')
```

[image]